# Adding raisedbutton child to my test code returns child syntax error

Tags: flutter

The below code showed error in the .dart file when I added a raised button child as below code. Is there any way I can avoid the error and understand why it is happening?

```dart
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
   return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
   );
}

Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
   final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
   return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.name),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child:  Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),

      child: ListTile(
             title: Text(record.name),
             trailing:
             Text(record.votes.toString()),
             //  onTap: () => print(record),
             //       onTap: () => record.reference.updateData({'votes': record.votes + 1})
             onTap: () => record.reference.updateData({'votes': FieldValue.increment(1)})
         ),
         child:
           RaisedButton(
             child: Text('Open route'),textColor:(Colors.amber),
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
               );
             },
           ),
     )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are missing (,) after Text("Press please"), .

Comment: You can't add multiple `child` to `Container` widget. Try using `Column` or `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing (,) after text widget.

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text("press please"),  // here (,) is missing
          onPressed: () {
            // here navigator
          },
        ),
```

Update:

You can not add multiple child in container, you can use Column and inside it you can add multiple widgets.

Sample code:

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.name),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
                title: Text(record.name),
                trailing: Text(record.votes.toString()),
                //  onTap: () => print(record),
                //       onTap: () => record.reference.updateData({'votes': record.votes + 1})
                onTap: () => record.reference
                    .updateData({'votes': FieldValue.increment(1)})),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Open route'),
              textColor: (Colors.amber),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I made the following :child:
           RaisedButton(
             child: Text('Open route'),textColor:(Colors.amber),

             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
               );
             },
           ),

Comment: yes definitely correct. is it not working ? if not then add all code, here as a text.

Comment: Thank you Viren. its work fine but it's show button in each column I need to add a button at the end of the screen like he need to navigate to the second screen

Comment: Then don't add button here, wrap your listview with column and use shrinkwrap:true property in listview. Then below listview add this button. If you found my answer useful then accept it.

Comment: I add shrinkwrap: true but its still show button in each results/record. my concern is to have once time at the top of down of the page.

Comment: read my full comment, i told you to remove button from this column. i told you to Wrap listView with column and below listview add this button.

Comment: If it works for you then accept my answer.@Abdallah